# Firebase auth auth/invalid-action-code when using a code twice

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to log in users via an email link.

The second time the user uses the link I get this error:

> auth/invalid-action-code: Thrown if the action code is invalid. This can happen if the code is malformed, expired or has already been used.

I know the code is not malformed because it works on the first time. So the code might be expired or already in use. But, I don't want the codes to ever expire or have a maximum number of uses (the user should be able to use it as many times as he wants).

What can I do?

Comment: That's not possible but why do you want to use same token multiple times? What is the use case? There might be some other option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A sign-in link can be used only once. You'll have to implement your own system if you want permanent tokens e.g. storing the token in a database like Firestore, using a Cloud Function to verify the user with your logic, and signing in the user with [custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens). However, I won't recommend using the same token multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I want to use the same token to make it easier for the user to login in different devices. Right now, he needs to type in his email again and again every time he changes device/browser.

Comment: There isn't any built in way to do so. But again, it'll be hard to manage such a system like handling revoking tokens and all.